# Python packaging: create directory in homedir during installation

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am creating a Python package whose features include logging certain actions in a database. Thus I would like to store the database in a location such as `~/.package-name/database.sqlite`. Additionally, `~/.package-name` could be a directory to hold configuration files.

What is the best practice for doing this? I am using `setuptools` to handle package installation. I imagine that within one of my modules, I would have code that checks for the existence of the database file and config file(s), creating them if necessary.

Reading the [documentation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#non-package-data-files), it states

> you can’t actually install data files to some arbitrary location on a user’s machine; this is a feature, not a bug. You can always include a script in your distribution that extracts and copies your the documentation or data files to a user-specified location, at their discretion.

It seems that I cannot create the location `~/.package-name` using `setuptools`. So should I create this directory the first time the user runs the program by checking for the directory and invoking a script or function?

Is there a standard sort of example I might look at? I had some trouble searching for my problem.

Comment: May be better to include an init script that a user can run the first time they want to use your package.  Or, have your package check for and, if needed, do initialization when it is run.  Consider the case where your package is installed system-wide, and is used by a number of different users.

Comment: It seems that is the sensible option. If no configuration/database, run script to create it. It'd also make sense for me to have separate configs per user/home directory.